# Button inside ListView is not working

Tags: android, listview, buttonclick

I am using ListView for making this layout(ScreenShot). Here when I click Button 1st, it is not worked. But if I click ListItem 1st then I click Button it works.

[image]

Even I used **android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"** in the layout.
**android:focusable="false" & android:focusableInTouchMode="false"** inside of Button. But nothing worked.

Please help me to fix it.

My Codes:
**xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardlist_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/curved_shape"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        card_view:cardElevation="7dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/image_4" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="14dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cartProduct"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Fusce veh"
                        android:textColor="#9F9F9F" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cartQuantity"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="100 g"
                        android:textColor="#9F9F9F" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="225dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/symbol"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:text="Rs "
                            android:textColor="#9F9F9F" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/cartPrice"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.48"
                            android:text="19.99"
                            android:textColor="#9F9F9F" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/cartPriceDum"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.48"
                            android:text="19.99"
                            android:textColor="#9F9F9F"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivDecrease"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.1"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_expand" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/cartCount"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="1"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivIncrease"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.1"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_collapse" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:background="#E4E4E4" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#F8F8F8"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/addTowish"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:background="#F8F8F8"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:text="ADD TO WISHLIST"
                    android:textColor="#787878" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#E4E4E4" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/remove"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:background="#F8F8F8"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:text="REMOVE"
                    android:textColor="#787878" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Handle that Button click functionality from your adapter. This will solve your problem..

Comment: Yeah.It s working. Thank you

Comment: Having a doubt @Chaitu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add clicklistener to your button inside adapter class

```
public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        CardView cardClick = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.xxx);

        btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.xxx);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");

        cardClick.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` from both your buttons.

Since you have disabled focusability it doesn't react on click the first time. When you click on the listview the row gains focus and hence its working.

Also remove `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` from the linear layout that holds the buttons.